# Confused with PyQt5 QFileDialog

Tags: python, pyqt5, qfiledialog

I'm trying to write a simple script with GUI file select dialog box and return the selected file name to the main program code. I've looked up some ideas online, but I'm confused as to how this all works. I have the following code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QInputDialog, QLineEdit, QFileDialog, QMessageBox
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon

class App(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = 'Bla'
        self.left = 10
        self.top = 10
        self.width = 640
        self.height = 480
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)

        self.openFileNameDialog()

        self.show()

    def openFileNameDialog(self):
        options = QFileDialog.Options()
        options |= QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog
        fileName, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self,"QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()", "","All Files (*);;Python Files (*.py)", options=options)

        return(fileName)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    alert = QMessageBox()
    alert.setText(f'selected file {ex}')
    alert.exec_()    
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I've added a message box to see whether file selection is working fine, but if I run it the message box displays:

```
selected file <_main_.App object at 0x0000000002EA9288>
```

At the same time, when I put my message box inside openFileNameDialog, everything works fine:

```
~snip~

def openFileNameDialog(self):
        options = QFileDialog.Options()
        options |= QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog
        fileName, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self,"QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()", "","All Files (*);;Python Files (*.py)", options=options)

        alert = QMessageBox()
        alert.setText(f'selected file {fileName}')
        alert.exec_()

~snip~
```

So the question is how do I return the filename back to the main program properly? Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- *What is `ex`?* It is a variable that represents the widget, it is not the fileName.
- *What returns openFileNameDialog is saved in some variable?* No, then that information is lost. If you want to obtain the information created in some method then an alternative is to save it as an attribute of the class.

Considering the above, the solution is:

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QFileDialog, QMessageBox


class App(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.fileName = ""
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle("Bla")
        self.setGeometry(10, 10, 640, 480)
        self.openFileNameDialog()
        self.show()

    def openFileNameDialog(self):
        options = QFileDialog.Options()
        options |= QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog
        fileName, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(
            self,
            "QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()",
            "",
            "All Files (*);;Python Files (*.py)",
            options=options,
        )
        self.fileName = fileName


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    alert = QMessageBox()
    alert.setText(f"selected file {ex.fileName}")
    alert.exec_()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I thought that this was the case but I couldn't figure out a correct way to code it. I've tried a couple different options but all failed.